# How can we see that there is superconductivity/superfluidity in the boundary theory in the holographic principle?

Tags: superconductivity, quantum-chromodynamics, ads-cft, holographic-principle, superfluidity

For example in the models for holographic superconductors we can calculate the conductivity. Also there is an energy gap. I can understand that it describes a superconductor. However I have also heard people talk about superfluidity in holographic QCD. I believe they are talking about the condensates such as the pion or the chiral condensate. Where is the superfluid in holographic QCD (quark gluon plasma maybe?) and how do I know that it is a superfluid?